# DataBinding With RecycleView Exception: ParentView is existed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am so wondering about DataBinding when I try to use it withing Recycle View or any case needs to inflate layout.xml

I am trying to connect recycle view with layout.xml which connected with DataBinding object. and I did these steps.

1) Recycle view holder.

```
public class StepperViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public final StepperViewBinding STEPPER_VIEW;

    StepperViewHolder(@NonNull StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding) {
        super(stepperViewBinding.getRoot());
        STEPPER_VIEW = stepperViewBinding;
    }
}
```

2) OnCreateViewHolder

```
@Override
public StepperViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(mActivity, R.layout.stepper_view);
    return new StepperViewHolder(stepperViewBinding);
}
```

Now, this exception is throwing.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
>                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:746)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)

**NOTE**
I get this exception previously when I tried to use library similar to recycle view processes by DataBinding view too.
And I solved this exception by removing view parent if it exists before `addView()` method [Within library code].

And at this exception the same error is happened at `addView()` method. 
So why this happens, and how can i avoid it?

Beside that I tried to remove view parent before passing it to ViewHolder and recycle view worked as well and both methods `onCreateView()` - `onBindView()` is called to but at mobile screen there's no views to show !!!
This is the steps I followed:-

1)

```
private void checkParentView(StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding){
    if(stepperViewBinding.getRoot().getParent() != null){
        ((ViewGroup)stepperViewBinding.getRoot().getParent()).removeView(stepperViewBinding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

2)

```
@Override
public StepperViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(mActivity, R.layout.stepper_view);
    // To avoid IllegalStateException.
    // State: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    checkParentView(stepperViewBinding);
    return new StepperViewHolder(stepperViewBinding);
}
```

**SOLVED**
by creating instance of binding views by this way.

```
StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mActivity),
            R.layout.stepper_view, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong method of `DataBindingUtil`. From reading the documentation, `setContentView()` should only be used when you want to change the content view of an `Activity`, which would not be applicable in a `RecyclerView`. Instead, I think you should use [the `inflate()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean,%20android.databinding.DataBindingComponent)):

```
@Override
public StepperViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    StepperViewBinding stepperViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.stepper_view, parent, false);
    return new StepperViewHolder(stepperViewBinding);
}
```